# Combobox values in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Recently i was coding an Point of sale system , in my system when the people that work at the store try to enter a new product in the database they should select if the product is a piece if it's a drink should be an L (liter), if it is vegetables like pears , apples (KG) kilograms . I created an string names tip(type) but i get an error , not every time i insert a product the type appears.

Here is my code:

```
konekcija = New MySqlConnection
    konekcija.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=baza;port=3307"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim kupovnacena As Double
    Dim prodaznacena As Double
    Dim kolicina As Double
    Dim profit As Double
    Dim ddv As Double
    Dim mkpr As String
    Dim edmerka As String
 If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 1 Then


            edmerka = "парче"


        End If
        If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 2 Then


            edmerka = "кг"


        End If
        If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 3 Then


            edmerka = "мг"


        End If
        If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 4 Then


            edmerka = "Л"


        End If

 COMMAND.Connection = konekcija

        COMMAND.CommandText = "INSERT INTO baza.artikli VALUES(@kod,@naziv,@nabavna,@prodazna,@ddv,@kolicina,@opis,@opis2,@mkproizvod,@profit,@proizvoditel,@edmerka)"
        COMMAND.Prepare()



        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kod", TextBoxBarkod.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naziv", TextBoxNaziv.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nabavna", TextBoxKupovna.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodazna", TextBoxProdazna.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddv", ddv)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kolicina", TextBoxKolicina)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opis", TextBoxOpis.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opis2", TextBoxOpis2.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mkproizvod", mkpr)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profit", profit)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proizvoditel", TextBoxProizvoditel.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edmerka", edmerka)


        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Use parameters and use `COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()`. You're doing an insert so you don't need `READER`.

Comment: You’re vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [parameterized queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html).

Comment: I am not asking for help with my data insertion , it works fine , the software is used in a local computer NOT connected to the internet also the data is not secret.

Comment: Your question is far too vague..... More specifics are required. YOu should also use types or classes to fill the ComboBox and look at ComboBox3.SelectedItem instead of doing a string of hard coding a list of If's like that.

Comment: And don't underestimate the effects of the security issue... Disgruntled employees can cause havoc.

Comment: @Trajkovski sorry, my comment was merely to advise on what I felt was a flaw in your code. As for the error at hand, it wasn't really clear to me so I didn't divulge into it. One thing that could be useful though is to include the _error_ and _where_ you get it within your code. However that being said my comment does stand. You should use parameters and Ryan has provided a link for you there and you don't need a reader. Instead use `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: `the software is used in a local computer NOT connected to the internet also the data is not secret.` - And what happens when an evil employee with some degree of computer knowledge decides to input `'); DROP TABLE baza.artikli -- ` in one of the text boxes?

Comment: Hey , thanks friends , i changed the code , i hope this one is good , but i get an error now "column count dont match vaule 1 "

Comment: I know very little about SQL, so I'm afraid I can't be of help with that error... However you should say at what line you get it.

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: I think you should add the columns back after the `INSERT INTO` statement, like so: `INSERT INTO baza.artikli(column1, column2, ...)`.

Comment: What @VisualVincent said. Add the columns back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to test if the selected index is equal to 0 :
`If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
       edmerka = "something"
 End If`

Answer (score 1):

Do not hard code things like that... And use the SelectedItem property of Combo Boxes.

Create a structure to hold your ComboBox option items.

```
 Private Structure ListItem
        Public Value As String
        Public Name As String
        Public Sub New(New_Name As String, New_Value As String)
            Value = New_Value
            Name = New_Name
        End Sub
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Name
        End Function
    End Structure
```

Then where you initialize the combobox use the following.

```
    ComboBox3.Items.Add(New ListItem("Whatever", "парче"))
    ComboBox3.Items.Add(New ListItem("This", "кг"))
    ComboBox3.Items.Add(New ListItem("Means", "мг"))
    etc.
```

Then in your subroutine simply use...

```
Dim edmerka As String = DirectCast(ComboBox3.SelectedItem, ListItem).Value
```

If item 0 is something like "Please Select" then you will need to add a first item with a value you can test for. Then test it after the above line.

```
ComboBox3.Items.Add(New ListItem("Whatever", "")) 'Added before the others

If emberka ="" then
    'warn user and exit sub
end if
```

**ALSO**

As others have mentioned, use Paramaters in your query so you are not susceptible to sql insertion. It may be a closed office situation, but DO NOT underestimate the effects of the security issue... **Disgruntled employees can cause havoc.**

Comment: You should use `DirectCast` or `TryCast` rather than `CType`. The latter should only be used when you want to convert from another type and you have defined conversion operators.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @VisualVincent. I use CType because if I just try to assign it without any conversion the IDE prompts me to use the cType method. I figured.. well if you say so... LOL. In this case I think CType is sufficient since I know what the source is. But good point none the less.

Comment: `In this case I think CType is sufficient since I know what the source is` - Though it's when you know what the source is that you should be using `Try-/DirectCast`. ;)

Comment: In many cases `CType` compiles to a simple cast.  `CType(Image.FromStream(ms), Bitmap)`  compiles to `(Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms)`  which is exactly what `DirectCast` compiles to. The compiler isnt stupid which is why the VB Error Fix thing offers CType.

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix  I have leaned more on here from answering questions than asking them... LOL

Comment: I can't understand why this would get downvoted? It's a rather good solution!

Comment: Also, protip on how to tell when to use `CType` or `DirectCast`: Use the former when you want to convert the source object into _another type_, and use the latter when you want to get the source object from a generic type (i.e. from `System.Object`). -- For instance, for events and their `sender` parameter you'd use `DirectCast` since you just want the source object directly, you don't want to convert it to another type.

Comment: I think the down vote  was something personal @VisualVincent. I got hit with 5 down votes in 5 different questions within the space of 3 minutes. I have no clue as to why.....

Comment: [**Been there as well**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323071/what-to-do-about-voting-fraud). It's sad how some people never grow up.